# postgres crosstab, ERROR: The provided SQL must return 3 columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Hello I have created a view, but want to pivot it.

OUTPUT before pivoting:

```
   tag1  |  qmonth1  |  qmonth2  |  sum1
 --------+-----------+-----------+--------
 name1   |  18-05   |  MAY      |  -166
 name2   |  18-05   |  MAY      |  -86
 name3   |  18-05   |  MAY      |  35
 name1   |  18-06   |  JUN      |  -102
 name2   |  18-06   |  JUN      |  -32
 name3   |  18-06   |  JUN      |  -75
 name1   |  18-09   |  AVG      |  -135
 name2   |  18-09   |  AVG      |  -52
 name3   |  18-09   |  AVG      |  -17
```

expected output:

```
 qmonth2 | name1 | name2 | name3
 --------+-------+-------+-------
  MAY    | -166  | -86  |  35
  JUN    | -102  | -32  | -75
  AVG    | -135  | -52  | -17
```

my full query:

```
SELECT tag1,qmonth2,sum1 FROM crosstab 
('SELECT tag1::text,qmonth1,qmonth2::text,sum1::numeric 
FROM public."chartdata_chart3"') 
AS ct ( "tag1" TEXT,"qmonth2" TEXT,"sum1" NUMERIC);
```

I getting this error and unable to resolve:

```
ERROR:  invalid source data SQL statement
DETAIL:  The provided SQL must return 3 columns: rowid, category, and values.
SQL state: 22023
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL statement passed as paremeter to `crosstab()` function must return one row_name column, one category column, and one value column. This in your case is qmonth2, tag1 and sum1.

This is your query considering `sum1` is an integer, `qmonth2` and `tag1` are text:

```
select *
from crosstab(
  'select qmonth2, tag1, sum1
  from public."chartdata_chart3"
  ') AS ct(qmonth2 text, name1 int, name2 int, name3 int;
```

Output:

```
 qmonth2 | name1 | name2 | name3
---------+-------+-------+-------
 MAY     | -166  | -86   | 35
 JUN     | -102  | -32   | -75
 AVG     | -135  | -52   | -17
```

Refer to [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) for more information and samples on how `crosstab` works.

Also, keep in mind that naming your columns/tables with quotes makes it more complex to write every SQL query so you are better off without doing that :)

Comment: it did worked, but had to changed INT to NUMERIC, as they are negative values, Also is it possible to make the NAME1 & NAME2 & NAME3 column headers automatic, so i don't need to change them if i select different data for TAG1??

Comment: @michal integers also cover negative values. Use numeric type to handle numbers with fractional parts. If you want to have dynamic headers there's a way using `crosstab(text, text)` function but if the number of columns might change then you would need a dynamic SQL (more complex) to cover the example.